# Plotting and saving graphs inside function?

Tags: python, function, seaborn

I have a GUI that returns depreciation rates/amount to fixed assets according to different countries. I am trying to include a function that returns/prints/saves plots of the depreciated amounts. I am not sure how to return the figure or how to save it at least.

here's the code of the graph function: (from an example at the seaborn website)

```
def graphs_make(dfA):

    if args.Graphs == 'YES':
        sns.set(style="whitegrid")

        # Initialize the matplotlib figure
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15))

        # Plot the total value
        sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
        sns.barplot(x="Value", y="Asset Class", data=dfA,
                    label="Total Value", color="b")

        # Plot the depreciated amounts
        sns.set_color_codes("muted")
        sns.barplot(x="Depreciated_Amount", y="Asset Class", data=dfA,
                    label="Depreciated", color="b")

        # Add a legend and informative axis label
        ax.legend(ncol=2, loc="lower right", frameon=True)
        ax.set(xlim=(0, 24), ylabel="",
               xlabel="Depreciated amount vs. Total Value")
        sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)


    return dfA
```

When I run the GUI nothing happens relating to the graphs, I am not sure what to add inside the function to tell python to show the graphs or save them

Comment: `f.show()` should show the picture using the (default) backend, which can be checked with `plt.get_backend()`. On the other side, `f.savefig('filename.png')` saves the figure to disk, in the desired format. `f.canvas.get_supported_filetypes()` presents the list of supported formats for the plotting backend.

Comment: `plt.show()`! (`f.show()`) only works if an event loop is already running)